# Parse XML File with Python and get the letter 'u' in every list element

Tags: python, xml, regex, list, parsing

I have a XML file with some elements like this:

```
<RMS>[14.470156174, 14.470156174, 14.485567944, 14.496014765]</RMS>
```

I want to get a list with all the elements

So i tried some Regex with the following code:

```
      string = dom.getElementsByTagName('RMS')[0].toxml()
      string2 = re.findall("[\-]*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*", string)
```

Now, when I want to print the list, it looks like this:

```
      [u'14.470156174', u'14.470156174', u'14.485567944', u'14.496014765']
```

What's going on with the 'u'?

Are there any ideas how to solve the problem?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5):

Strings that start with a `u` are [unicode string literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings). Since XML contains unicode data, the XML parser returns your data in the correct type, which is the python [`unicode()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode).

You do not need to remove them, you do not have a problem. You may want to read up on Unicode and Python in the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) but there is no problem here.

Since these are numbers, you can convert the unicode values straight to float instances.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regex here. In fact, your regex may not work for some floats such as `1.4e1`.

Since you are using minidom you could do this:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
import ast

content = "<RMS>[14.470156174, 14.470156174, 14.485567944, 14.496014765]</RMS> "
dom = minidom.parseString(content)
text = dom.getElementsByTagName('RMS')[0].childNodes[0].wholeText
```

If you

```
print(text)
```

you get

```
[14.470156174, 14.470156174, 14.485567944, 14.496014765]
```

but if you

```
print(repr(text))
```

you get

```
u'[14.470156174, 14.470156174, 14.485567944, 14.496014765]'
```

The `u` indicates that `text` is a `unicode` object, not a `str` object. Similarly, your code produces a list of `unicode` objects. When you print a list, Python prints the `repr` of each of the elements inside the list. This is why you see

```
[u'14.470156174', u'14.470156174', u'14.485567944', u'14.496014765']
```

Now upon rereading your question, I see you want a list of the elements in `text`. Since they are numbers, I assume you want a list of floats. In that case, you could use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
values = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(values)
```

yields

```
[14.470156174, 14.470156174, 14.485567944, 14.496014765]
```

where `values` is a list of floats.

Comment: The OP *is* using the minidom (and thus a XML parser), and only using a regular expression for the element text. Both lxml and ElementTree will return unicode values as well.

Comment: Your new example is *also* returning a unicode string, but using `print` masks that. Remove the `print` statement and it'll show you the `u'[...]'` string (on Python 2.x of course).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The OP says, "I want to print the list". I take it he wants to print the list without seeing the `repr`s. I showed him how to do it without using regex.

Comment: I'm not convinced the printing of the list is the end goal though.